# Repeated checking of ID path parameter in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, api, dependency-injection, fastapi

I have the following route specs:

```
GET    /councils/{id}
PUT    /councils/{id}
DELETE /councils/{id}
```

In all three routes, I have to check in the database whether the council with the `id` exists, like this:

```py
council = crud.council.get_by_id(db=db, id=id)
    if not council:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail='Council not found'
        )
```

Which adds to a lot of boilerplate in the code. Is there any way of reducing this? I have thought of creating a dependency but then I have to write different dependency function for different models in my database. Is there any standard practice for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a dependency is the way to go - it allows you to extract the logic around "get a valid council from the URL"; you can generalize it further if you want to map `/<model>/<id>` to always retrieving something from a specific model; however - you might want to validate this against a set of possible values to avoid people trying to make you load random Python identifiers in your models class.

```
from fastapi import Path

def get_council_from_path(council_id: int = Path(...),
                          db: Session = Depends(get_db),
):
  council = crud.council.get_by_id(db=db, id=id)

  if not council:
    raise HTTPException(
      status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
      detail='Council not found'
    )

  return council


@app.get('/councils/{council_id}')
def get_council(council: Council = Depends(get_council_from_path)):
  pass
```

You can generalize the dependency definition to make it reusable (I don't have anything available to test this right now, but the idea should work):

```py
def get_model_from_path(model, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
  def get_model_from_id(id: int = Path(...)):
    obj = model.get_by_id(db=db, id=id)

    if not council:
      raise HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        detail='{type(model)} not found'
      )

  return get_model_from_id


@app.get('/councils/{id}')
def get_council(council: Council = Depends(get_model_from_path(crud.council)):
  pass
```

Comment: I like this.  The fact that I have to directly import and use the required crud object instead of my solution where the exact same name as it was imported in the module's `__init__` needs to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that works. FastAPI supports classes as dependencies. Therefore I can have a class like this:

```py
class DbObjIdValidator:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        if name not in dir(crud):
            raise ValueError('Invalid model name specified')
        
        self.crud = getattr(crud, name)

    def __call__(self, db: Session = Depends(get_db), *, id: Any):
        db_obj =  self.crud.get_by_id(db=db, id=id)
        if not db_obj:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                detail='not found'
            )
        
        return db_obj
```

Considering `crud` module imports the crud classes for all the ORM models. My example is closely following the [fastAPI cookiecutter project](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql) by Tiangolo, and the crud design pattern he followed.

Now in order to use it, for example in `councils_route.py`, I can do the following:

```py
router = APIRouter(prefix='/councils')

council_id_dep = DbObjIdValidator('council') # name must be same as import name

@router.get('/{id}', response_model=schemas.CouncilDB)
def get_council_by_id(
    id: UUID, 
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
    council: Councils = Depends(council_id_dep)    
):

    return council
```

Comment: This can be further modified by following @MatsLindh's answer.

`def __init__(self, *, model: CRUDBase): self.crud = model`
and, instantiate it like `council_id_dep = DbObjIdValidator(model=crud.council)`